# How to hide data displayed on the terminal while executing tshark?

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I need to hide data that is displayed while executing tshark command line for wireshark:

```
tshark -i tun0 -T ek -w /home/PCAP_Folder/Sim_Run1st.pcap
```

I am running two program simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

The following will send the output to `/dev/null`:

```
tshark -i tun0 -T ek -w /home/PCAP_Folder/Sim_Run1st.pcap > /dev/null
```

If you also want to hide any error message:

```
tshark -i tun0 -T ek -w /home/PCAP_Folder/Sim_Run1st.pcap &> /dev/null
```

Note that if you also hide the error messages, the `-T ek` option becomes pointless.